# Windows 7 has broken icons that look the same

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, icons, shortcuts, start-menu

My daughter has done something to her Windows 7 PC, but I'm not sure what and she can't quite remember. She is not an Administrator on her machine so it perturbs me that she has broken it so well. Anyway, the symptoms are all the icons in the task bar and All Programs menu have the same icon (which happens to the be the virtual CloneDrive icon).

If I try and launch a program such as Calculator, this happens:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/J4qH2.png]

Is there a way to quickly restore all the icons? I can't do a System Restore because some programs have been installed since the problem appeared.

Comment: the fastest way to solve this issues is to uninstall CloneDrive and reinstall it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I did in preparation for writing to the registry thanks to jnpcl's suggestion,  was to make the user account an Administrator. I logged off and back on and the icons returned to normal. I then made the user account Restricted, logged off and on and they remained fine. Strange. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Shortcut (.lnk) files have been associated with the program 'VCDMount'..

**Fix here:** http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19449-default-file-type-associations-restore.html

**Direct link:** http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/159134d1312706820-default-file-type-associations-restore-default_lnk_-shortcut-.reg

Comment: Looks like you've been a bit faster ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe everything is set to open with VCD. Try right-clicking an image for example and go to "open with". Then choose to select a standard program. Set this to your image viewer.

I don't know how to do it with everything at once, but you can try this to see if this is actually the problem.